Error: Error: SaTScan in the continuous Poisson model
When I run the analysis using the continuous Poisson model in SaTScan, defining the polygon as everything within the distances between the furthest points on the map, I get the following message: "Error: Record 74 in the coordinate file contains a coordinate that is not within any of the defined polygons." Could someone explain if I am defining the polygon correctly?
